# Image resize with jquery

Tags: jquery

need jquery image resize, like if image width > 400 then use resize width:50%, other images that is smaller size like 100X100 dont need to be resized.

I use this code

```
var max_size = 400;
$(".comment p.message a.fancy img").each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
    var h = max_size;
    var w = Math.ceil($(this).width() / $(this).height() * max_size);
  } else {
    var w = max_size;
    var h = Math.ceil($(this).height() / $(this).width() * max_size);
  }
  $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
});
```

But this code dont check smaller images.

Comment: I don't know if that's the solution already but the correct notation for passing an object to .css() would be `$(this).css({ 'height': h, 'width': w });`

Comment: @m90: `{height: h, width: w}` is fine.

Comment: @mu is too short: had the exact same problem yesterday and not using quotes threw an error for me?

Comment: Ok, problem seemed to be _"Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name."_ in my case as I was going for `top-margin` in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aJffu/2/

```
var maxsize = 400;

$("#images img").each(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var maxdim = Math.max(t.width(), t.height());
    if (maxdim > maxsize) {
        t.css({
            width: t.width() / 2,
            height: t.height() / 2
        });
    }
});
```

This halves the size of the image if either the width or height exceeds `maxsize`. Shouldn't be hard to adapt this to your specific needs. For example, [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/aJffu/3/) scales the image such that the the longest dimension is `maxsize`.